# C# generic method with inheritance and interface

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

this is something really simple Im sure, but Im struggling to get my head around the inheritance malarky when it comes to interfacing.

Given the following classes, how do I interface the Get method in an interface specific to class Parent, without overriding the base method?

```
public class Base<T, T2>
{
    public T Get<T, T2>(string key)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Parent : Base<Type1, Type2>, IParent
{
    ...
}
```

Here's what I have atm, but I keep getting a "inteface member Type1 IParent.Get(string) is not implemented" error.

```
public interface IParent
{
    Type1 Get(string key);
}
```

Comment: You do not need the `Get<T,T2>` in the method if they are already declared in the class.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, it has helped me to understand it much better. ja72, Krizz, Charles & Guvante all hit the nail on the head, but Charles' description was the most in-depth (with code examples, no less) so he gets the green tick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `T Get<T,T2>(string)` method of `Base<T,T2>` and the method `Type1 Get(string)` method of `IParent` are two different method signatures. You would need to implement both. If you wanted both implementations to use the same functionality you could do the following:

```
public class ParentJ : Base<Type1, Type2>, IParent {
 public Type1 Get(string key) {
    return this.Get<Type1,Type2>(key);
 }
}
```

However I believe that your original intent is not to parameterize the `Get()` method in `Base<T,T2>` therefore you would write `Base` like so:

```
public class Base<T,T2> {
  public T Get(string key) {
    // implementation here
  }
}
```

That signature would satisfy the method signature in `IParent`.

You only need type parameters (e.g. `T` and `T2`) on methods when the type cannot or should not be inferred by the class that contains the method.

Answer (score 5):

`public T Get<T, T2>(string key)` will create a generic method on generic class. `T` and `T2` will be arguments of this generic method and will have no relation to class's `T` and `T2`.

Just make it `public T Get(string key)`.

Answer (score 2):

When matching methods, this signature must match exactly. One of the components of the signature is the number of generic arguments.

Your `IParent` interface contains a method `Get` with zero type arguments. Your `Base` class contains a method `Get` with two type arguments.

While it looks like `Base.Get` shares its type arguments, it does not, the syntax used creates two new type arguments that shadow the type arguments of the class.

The fix is to simply implement a `Get` method in `Parent` that does not have any type arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You do not override the base `Get` and you implement `IParent`.

```
public class Type1 { }
public class Type2 { }

public interface IParent
{
    Type1 Get(string key);
}

public class Base<T, T2> 
{
    public T Get(string key)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}
public class Parent : Base<Type1, Type2>, IParent
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try by using generic IParent interface.